# ProgressBar management in BaseActvity/BaseFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-progressbar

Read the Answer, If you are also facing similar problems in Android app like below

- Need to manage progress bar from a single place instead of every activity/fragment.
- Want to remove the ProgressDialog from your BaseAcivity/BaseFragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options to handling ProgreessBar in Android app. I would like to share my way. Hope it helps some one and save some time.

First of all We are adding a root progress bar in BaseActivity and Same progress bar using in BaseFragment

For Adding a progress bar in BaseActivity override the setContentView(layoutResID) method

**BaseActivity.kt**

```
lateinit var progressListener: ProgressListener
private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar

override fun setContentView(layoutResID: Int) {
    val coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_base, null) as CoordinatorLayout
    val activityContainer: FrameLayout = coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.layout_container)
    progressBar = coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.progressBar) as ProgressBar
    binder = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, layoutResId(), activityContainer, true)//to inflate a layout using Data binding 
    binder.lifecycleOwner = this
    super.setContentView(coordinatorLayout)
}

override fun onPostCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState)
        progressListener = ProgressListener(getProgressBar())
    }

/**
 *  open it for overload it in other child activity
 *  So in case
 *  If you want to use BaseProgress just ignore it, Don't need to override this fun
 *  If you want to your progressbar change, Just define in your xml and override the progress bar instance to base
 *  If you don't want to use Base as well any custom progress just override this and return null
 *  */
open fun getProgressBar(): ProgressBar? {
        return progressBar
    }
```

**ProgressListener.kt**

```
class ProgressListener(private val progressBar: ProgressBar?) {
    fun showLoading(isVisible: Boolean) {
        progressBar?.visibility = if (isVisible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
}
```

**activity_base.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

And Now For the BaseFragment just access the BaseActivity's progress bar using BaseActivity's instance, and rewrite the open fun for BaseFragment as well.

**Note: If you are facing some issue or If I am not able to clarifying the solution properly, Just comment below.**

Happy Coding :)